# Where do I find nft.storage authentication token for Metaplex Sugar?

Tags: nft, metaplex, candy-machine

I am new to using sugar, and I am running into an issue with nft_storage. When I run

```
$: sugar launch
```

I receive the following err

```
 Error running command (re-run needed): Invalid nft.storage authentication token.
```

I am unsure what is nft_storage authentication token as I have tried using the CID and url for the asset. Anyone knows where to find the authentication token for  nft_storage?

I already have uploaded the asstet to the nft.storage
[image]

So what I am looking for is the right way to add this to the config file.

Comment: The solution is to go to the API keys and create a new key and add it there, hopefully someone will find this useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yh as Greg mentioned in the comment it's the same thing so you must create a new API key from https://nft.storage/ and copy it and put it in the authentication token in sugar cli

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to go to the API keys and create a new key and add it there, hopefully someone will find this useful